# How to say "double-jointed" in Spanish?

Tags: vocabulario

In the context of "I am double-jointed in the elbows." (Writing a detailed description of self in my assignment)

I've looked it up online and composed "Soy con articulaciones dobles en mi codos" from online Spanish trans. sources, but I don't know if that's accurate, or if that's how a native/someone well versed would say it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several different ways to express double-jointedness.

- *Soy **hiperlaxo***
  <sup>Use if you want to keep parallel structure with other adjectives.  Not in the DRAE, but has a good usage online.</sup>
- *Tengo **articulaciones dobles***
  <sup>A colloquial form, obviously related to the English (though who borrowed/calqued from whom, I'm not sure).</sup>
- *Tengo **hiperlaxitud articular***.
  <sup>A slightly more technical sounding one, but perfectly usable.</sup>

Notice the latter two are the *names* of the condition, so you need to use them with *tener*.  The first one is an adjective that can be used with *ser*.  To say *double-jointed* as a modifier to a noun, you can either use *hiperlaxo* directly (*tengo codos hiperlaxos*) or use the latter two prefaced with *con* (*tengo codos con hiperlaxitud articular / articulaciones dobles*).

Comment: First two are commonly used. But I've heard the second is more used.

Comment: @Ustanak yeah, I confess to not having had many conversations on the topic, and between Google N-Grams and more general Google search, I couldn't determine a solid pattern of use.  N-Grams shows articulaciones dobles being much more common up to the 1950s ish, and now hiperlaxitud articular is more common (in books, at least, with *hiperlaxo* never used in print).  Online all three seem to be surprisingly roughly even split with some people using *doble articulación* as well, but I have no idea regional variations in usage, and G-hits aren't super accurate.

Comment: *Hiperlaxo* is a technical word and the DRAE usually does not include technical words. It does not mean that it is incorrect at all; it just falls outside its domain. In this case, since I've never actually seen or heard *articulaciones dobles*, I would go for the technical word, but your mileage may vary.